# Idiomatic way to run nested loop with passing value

Tags: loops, clojure, nested-loops, idioms, code-translation

I want to do something like this

```
int n=0
for(int i=xs; i<xe; i++){
  for(int j=ys; j<ye; j++){
    n++
  }
}
return n;
```

in Clojure way. Since all values are immutable, I think the value n should be passed as a parameter of a (possibly) recursive function. What is the best way to do so?

Comment: Doesn't this just return `(* (- xe xs) (- ye ys))` ?

Comment: If you plan to do something more interesting than `n++` in the inner loop body, the answer is probably going to depend on whether that thing has side-efects, such as printing, or whether the idea is to build a new collection of some sort, or transform existing collections, etc.  In most cases you can avoid recursion by using higher order functions.

Comment: @jas yes, that's per this example. in reality the n++ operation is something different, much more complicated. The point is how to hand the variable n over to the parameter in a nested recursion.

Comment: For just one example, see https://clojuredocs.org/clojure.core/map-indexed, but it's hard to say more without knowing more about what you're trying to do.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

the closest to your code would be

```
(defn f [xs xe ys ye]
  (let [n (atom 0)]
    (doseq [_ (range xs xe)
            _ (range ys ye)]
      (swap! n inc))
    @n))

user> (f 1 10 2 20)
;;=> 162
```

but the mutable atom approach is unidiomatic at all.

it could look like this, a bit more *clojure way*:

```
(defn f [xs xe ys ye]
  (count (for [_ (range xs xe)
               _ (range ys ye)]
           nil)))
#'user/f

user> (f 1 10 2 20)
;;=> 162
```

it really depends on what you're trying to do. Counting n's is obviously done better by `(* (- xe xs) (- ye ys))` , as @jas noticed, independent from what language you use )

what about recursive solution you mentioned, it could look like this:

```
(defn f [xs xe ys ye]
  (loop [n 0 i xs j ys]
    (cond (== j ye) n
          (== i xe) (recur n xs (inc j))
          :else (recur (inc n) (inc i) j))))
#'user/f

user> (f 1 10 2 20)
;;=> 162
```

Comment: I think the final loop example is closest to the spirit of the question, and is a perfectly natural thing to do in Clojure.

Answer (score 1):

Don't over-think the problem.  When you really need mutable state, you can always use an `atom`:

```
(defn calc
  [xs ys]
  (let [result (atom 0)]
    (doseq [x xs]
      (doseq [y ys]
        (swap! result + (* x y))))
    @result))

  (let [xs     [1 2 3]
        ys     [2 5 7 9]]
    (calc xs ys))
```

with result

```
(calc xs ys) => 138
```

You could also use a [volatile](https://clojuredocs.org/clojure.core/volatile%21).  It is like a non-thread-safe atom.  Note the use of `vswap!`:

```
(defn calc
  [xs ys]
  (let [result (volatile! 0)]
    (doseq [x xs]
      (doseq [y ys]
        (vswap! result + (* x y))))
    @result))
```

---

### Performance

In a tight loop, using a `volatile` makes a difference.  An example:

```
(ns tst.demo.core
  (:use tupelo.core tupelo.test)
  (:require [tupelo.profile :as prof]))

(def N 100)
(def vals (vec (range N)))

(prof/defnp summer-atom []
  (let [result (atom 0)]
    (doseq [i vals]
      (doseq [j vals]
        (doseq [k vals]
          (swap! result + i j k))))
    @result))

(prof/defnp summer-volatile []
  (let [result (volatile! 0)]
    (doseq [i vals]
      (doseq [j vals]
        (doseq [k vals]
          (vswap! result + i j k))))
    @result))

(dotest
  (prof/timer-stats-reset)
  (dotimes [i 10]
    (spyx (summer-atom))
    (spyx (summer-volatile)))
  (prof/print-profile-stats))
```

with result:

```
--------------------------------------
   Clojure 1.10.2-alpha1    Java 15
--------------------------------------

Testing tst.demo.core

(summer-atom)     => 148500000
(summer-volatile) => 148500000
...

---------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
Profile Stats:
   Samples       TOTAL        MEAN      SIGMA           ID
       10        2.739     0.273879   0.023240   :tst.demo.core/summer-atom                                                       
       10        0.383     0.038313   0.041246   :tst.demo.core/summer-volatile                                                   
---------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
```

So it makes about a 10x difference.  Probably not worthwhile unless you are doing at least a million operations like here (100^3).

For similar low-level operations on data structures, please see [transient!](https://clojuredocs.org/clojure.core/transient) and friends.

Especially bookmark the Clojure CheatSheet [from this list](https://github.com/io-tupelo/clj-template#documentation)

Answer (score 0):

I think here you can apply `reduce` function over `for`. What you do inside `loop-processing-fn` is up to you - it can be recursive as well.

```
(let [n-init 0 ;; your `n` variable
      xs 10 xe 20 ys -5 ye 5 ;; loop(s) ranges
      loop-processing-fn (fn [current-state [i j :as loop-data]]
                           (inc current-state) ;; anything here 
                           ) ;; processing function operating on state (n) and loop data

      ]
  (reduce loop-processing-fn n-init (for [i (range xs xe)
                                          j (range ys ye)]
                                      [i j])))
;; => 100
```

Answer (score 0):

Macros come to mind. I defined a macro `for-state` that I use like this:

```
(def xs 0)
(def xe 9)
(def ys 1)
(def ye 4)

(for-state
 i xs (< i xe) (inc i) n 0
 (for-state
  j ys (< j ye) (inc j) n n
  (inc n)))
;; => 27
```

Macros let you add new constructs that are hard to build using just functions. So if you have several nested loops of this kind, defining a macro like `for-state` could be an option:

```
(defmacro for-state [iter-var iter-init iter? iter-next    
                     state-var state-init state-next]
  `(loop [~iter-var ~iter-init
          ~state-var ~state-init]
     (if ~iter?
       (recur ~iter-next
              ~state-next)
       ~state-var)))
```

You can tweak it as you please. For example, you could group the macro arguments using vectors and do destructuring of those arguments to facilitate readability.